Could you help me understand where in my code I produce a list with a specific dimension?
I am reading force.txt files from series of folders nb100, nb200 ,nb300, ... . and I need to save the related results as result100, result200, ... in the related directories.
In order to do that I have written the following code:
 processFiles[folderName_String] := 
 Module[{directoryPath, rawforce, rcutoff, dC, mc, kB, 
 tem, \[Epsilon], \[Tau]0, cntA, funit, force, fTotal, test}, 
 directoryPath = FileNameJoin[{directory, folderName}];
 Print["Contents of directory: ", FileNames["*", directoryPath]];
 SetDirectory[directoryPath];
 rawforce = Import["force.txt", "Data"];
 rcutoff = 6.4633*10^(-10);
 dC = 1.2*10^(-9);
 cntA = \[Pi]*((rcutoff + dC/2)^2 - (rcutoff - dC/2)^2);
 mc = 5*1.99*10^-26;
 kB = 1.38*10^(-23);
 tem = 300;
 \[Epsilon] = kB*tem;
 \[Tau]0 = Sqrt[(mc*(rcutoff)^2)/\[Epsilon]];
 funit = (mc*rcutoff)/(\[Tau]0^2);
 (*change the shape of rawforce*)
 force = rawforce[[All, {2, 3}]];
 Print[Dimensions[rawforce]];
 Print[Dimensions[force]];
 fTotal = 
 Table[(Abs[force[[i, 1]]] + Abs[force[[i, 2]]]), {i, 1, 
  Length[rawforce]}];
 test = (fTotal*funit/cntA);
 (*Exporting results*)
 Export[FileNameJoin[{directoryPath, 
  "result" <> StringReplace[folderName, "nb" -> ""] <> ".txt"}], 
  test, "Table"];
  (*Assigning test to a unique variable*)
  Module[{varName = 
  Symbol["test" <> StringReplace[folderName, "nb" -> ""]]}, 
   varName = test;
  Evaluate[Symbol["ssp" <> StringReplace[folderName, "nb" -> ""]]] =
  varName;];
  Return[test];];

  processFiles["nb100"]

My force.txt data file looks like :
  1000 114.469 -123.654
  2000 114.314 -118.786
  3000 108.707 -115.067
  4000 124.734 -112.975
  5000 127.298 -102.803
  6000 104.415 -117.842
  7000 124.121 -102.191
  8000 113.309 -119.814
  9000 115.964 -115.679
  10000 110.652 -129.129
  11000 114.613 -93.9665
  12000 95.9005 -93.5025
  13000 62.1489 -59.0413
  14000 21.6795 -31.9267
  15000 -5.48211 1.18078
  16000 -23.1413 29.7669
  17000 -40.8841 28.8171
  18000 -57.8825 69.3712
  19000 -95.9343 80.1756
  20000 -123.399 93.1466

and I am getting the errors like:
Lists {3.2244560159333116*^8,0.,0.} and 3.129910672408923*^8 are 
not the same shape.
I am not sure where in the above code I produce a List with the above shape in the first place. So I did run the code for one directory out of the Module:
SetDirectory["/Users/delaram/Desktop/April11/nb100"]
FileNames[]
rawforce = Import["force.txt", "Data"]
rcutoff = 6.4633*10^(-10);
dC = 1.2*10^(-9);
cntA = \[Pi]*((rcutoff + dC/2)^2 - (rcutoff - dC/2)^2);
mc = 5*1.99*10^-26;
kB = 1.38*10^(-23);
tem = 300;
\[Epsilon] = kB*tem;
\[Tau]0 = Sqrt[(mc*(rcutoff)^2)/\[Epsilon]];
funit = (mc*rcutoff)/(\[Tau]0^2);
(*change the shape of rawforce*)
force = rawforce[[All, {2, 3}]]
fTotal = 
Table[(Abs[force[[i, 1]]] + Abs[force[[i, 2]]]), {i, 1, 
Length[rawforce]}]
test = (fTotal*funit/cntA)    

And I'm not producing that list according to the above code:
I am not sure how to fix the errors to get what I want.
Thank you so much.

"directory"  in  directoryPath = FileNameJoin[{directory, folderName}]; is not defined.
